# Providing name suggestions using user input

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so we have an array with names, and an input field where user enters a string and we want to give him name suggestions.Names Alex,Anna belong the array and for example when user enters "a" we want to make suggestion "Alex"and "Anna".Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<p class="thick"> Name*: </p> <input type="text" id="fullname"   onkeyup="myFunction();">

 <p id="test"></p>

 <script>
 var namesArray=   ["Alex","Anna","Eva","George","Jason","John","Lisa","Mary","Michael","Nick","Vicky"];
function myFunction() {
var text = document.getElementById('fullname').value;
var patt1 = new RegExp('^' + text, "i");

var result = [];
for (i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++) {
    if (patt1.test(namesArray[i]))
        result.push(namesArray[i]);
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result.join('<br />');
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It works fine expect one thing.When loaded for the first time, if i enter SPACE and then press DELETE the whole array is shown as name suggestion..I dont want that.I want a suggestion to come up only when the input field is non-empty.When user deletes what he has typed so far i want no suggestions to come up.How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing the array with a null value, so that when you type in space and delete, it knows not to search for anything. Possibly reinitialize the array after that.

Since your using `onkeyup`, after hitting space it's searching everything in the array that matches a space, which in this case seems to be everything in the array.

Comment: Initializing the array with a null value will fail when you call `.join` and may cause unusual results when the text is empty.

Answer (score 1):

While there are other improvements that could be made, the fix to your immediate problem involves checking the length of the string before suggesting results. If the input is empty, do not provide suggestions.

You can use a simple `str.length > 0` check, like:

```js
 var namesArray = ["Alex", "Anna", "Eva", "George", "Jason", "John", "Lisa", "Mary", "Michael", "Nick", "Vicky"];

 function myFunction() {
   var text = document.getElementById('fullname').value;

   var patt1 = new RegExp('^' + text, "i");

   var result = [];

   // Check length
   if (text.length > 0) {
     for (i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++) {
       if (patt1.test(namesArray[i]))
         result.push(namesArray[i]);
     }
   }

   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result.join('<br />');
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p class="thick">Name*:</p>
  <input type="text" id="fullname" onkeyup="myFunction();">

  <p id="test"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes it was that simple...Thanks a lot

Comment: You may also want to trim (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) your text.

Comment: @Blue there are a pile of other fixes that could be made, including trimming the text. However, please don't link w3schools; their tutorials and explanations are often wrong and do not reflect best practices.